# Problem using svnsync with svnserve and auth-access

Tags: svn, svnsync, svnserve

### CREATE A REPOSITORY 'repo1'

```
svnadmin create repo1
```

### CHANGE DIRECTORY conf

Contents of svnserve.conf

```
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd.txt
authz-db = authz.txt
realm = Home SVN Server
```

Contents of password.txt

```
[users]
susanta = susanta
```

Contents of authz.txt

```
[/]
susanta = rw
```

### RUN 'repo1'

```
svnserve -d -r c:/repo1 --listen-port 3691
```

### CREATE A MIRROR

```
svnadmin create repo1_mirror
```

CREATEd file pre-revprop-change.cmd in hooks

Contents of pre-revprop-change.cmd

```
exit 0
```

### SVNSYNC init

```
svnsync init file:///c:/repo1_mirror svn://localhost:3691/
```

Output:
Copied properties for revision 0.

### SVNSYNC sync

```
svnsync sync file:///c:/repo1_mirror

Output:
Committed revision 1.
Copied properties for revision 1.
Committed revision 2.
Copied properties for revision 2.
Committed revision 3.
Copied properties for revision 3.
Committed revision 4.
Copied properties for revision 4.
```

### Check repo1_mirror

```
svnserve -d -r c:/repo1_mirror --listen-port 3692
```

### Use TortoiseSVN to view

It is empty

NOTE: I ran the tests with no authentication in svnserve.conf and everything was fine. I am pretty sure something with authorization is creating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is has for sure to do with the authentication. Did TortoiseSVN ask you for your password?

if not consider disabling anonymous access at all in svnserve.conf

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd.txt
authz-db = authz.txt
realm = Home SVN Server
```

or allow read access in the authz.txt file.

```
[/]
* = r
susanta = rw
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and it worked. Yes, the TortoiseSVN asked for the password. That surprised me a bit since it had anonymous read access. But svnsync does not. so, svnsync figures out that the source has anon read access but does not transmit data for the new revisions. Supplying svnsync with --source-username and password does not make it transmit the data either which is fine since read access should be enough for svnsync.